# javascirpt toggle fade effects

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a question.

In Vue.js, you can easily specify the fade in / fade out effect through the  component.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
</div>
```

I wonder how to implement it directly without using the transition component.

I've tried a few times myself, but I'm having difficulties, and if I search, only jQuery examples are coming out.

I want to know how!

Comment: Directly? Do you mean using CSS? Or something like JavaScript?

Comment: @evolutionxbox
both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Vue**, without the `<transition>` element, use binding via `:class`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

```css
.item {
  transition: opacity .5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <button @click="show = !show">Toggle</button>
  <div class="item" :class="{'is-active' : show}">hello</div>
</div>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

In JavaScript you would use the `classList.toggle()` :

```js
const toggleTarget = (evt) =>  {
  const selector = evt.currentTarget.dataset.toggle;
  document.querySelectorAll(selector)
    .forEach(EL => EL.classList.toggle("u-transparent"));
};

document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle]")
  .forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", toggleTarget));
```

```css
.item {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

/* UTILITY CLASSES, ATOMS */

.u-transparent {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<button data-toggle="#item_1">Toggle</button>
<div id="item_1" class="item">hello</div>
```

Comment: **Thank you!** @NVRM feel free to comment!

Comment: Is it possible to toggle the css display property? (display: block; / display: none;)

Comment: @zero86 yes, but not with a transition - it will be instant. Try it!